# Why is my ArrayList not being saved to my file?

Tags: java, arraylist, printwriter

Why is ArrayList not being written into "MyCalendar.txt"? Even when I use out.write() it still returns false but does not write to the file.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public static Boolean addAppointment(ArrayList<String> calendar, 
                     String specifiedDay,
                         String specifiedTime) {

PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("myCalendar.txt"); //declare calendar file    


    for (int i = 0; i<calendar.size(); i++) {
        String index = calendar.get(i);
        if (index.equals(specifiedDay + "" + specifiedTime))
        { 
         out.println(specifiedDay + "" + specifiedTime);
         return false; 
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You should have `PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("myCalendar.txt");` surrounded by a `try`/`catch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below 2 are important to flush data to file and close the stream

```
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Regards,

Comment: Closing the stream will automatically flush the stream.

Comment: Thank you! We were never taught to flush the data during class, but that was apparently what I needed to do. Also, I used out.write(specifiedDay + specifiedTime + '\n') to save it in the file.

Comment: if you use out.println then you don't need \n. Because println means print the line and terminate. But if you use out.write() then you need to use \n to write the line and terminate. So the next writing will start with the new line. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to close it:

```
out.close()
```

Comment: You might also need to `out.flush()` before closing.

Comment: @Joe, close automatically flushes the content to file before closing the stream. So flush is kind of optional.

Answer (score 0):

So, a couple of things here.

If you're using Java 7, you should consider using [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).  This will absolutely ensure that your `PrintWriter` is closed after you're done.

```
try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("somefile.txt")) {
    // code
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Bang!");
}
```

Next, there are a few cases in which the file could not be written to, either in part or at all:

- `calendar.size() == 0`
- `index.equals(specifiedDay + "" + specifiedTime)`

If the first condition is met, nothing is written and the method happily returns `true`.  Probably not what you expected.

If the second condition is met, you write the *first* element, and early return.  It would probably be a better idea to place that in your loop condition, and return the return value when you're done looping.

```
int i = 0;
boolean good = true;
while(good && i < calendar.size()) {
    // critical actions
    String index = calendar.get(i);
    if(index.equals(specifiedDay + "" + specifiedTime)) {
        good = false;
    }
}
// other code
return good;
```

If that condition is *never* met, then nothing is *ever* written to the file.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of PrintWriter is not to automatically flush the buffer. See the [PrintWriter Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) for more details.

Alternatively, you might have a data issue:

```
String index = calendar.get(i);
if (index.equals(specifiedDay + "" + specifiedTime))
```

If this condition isn't satisfied, you won't print anything out.  Have you made sure this condition is true?